# What's the PowerShell script to push Windows from version 21H2 to 22H2 during an unattended deployment?

Tags: windows, powershell, automation, scripting, windows-update

I have a powershell script to run windows updates as a post-installation task during an unattended windows deployment. It runs all the updates fine but won't make the jump from 21H2 to 22H2

I tried tweaking the script with the line: Get-WindowsUpdate -Install -KBArticleID 'KB5015684'
The task did not fail during the process, but the system still was at 21H2 after the unattend imaging process was done